# How to bind mouseover event after unbinding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm trying to get a nice animation with jQuery. I came up with that code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#arrow_up').hide();

    $('#arrow_down').bind({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('#content')
                .animate({
                    height: '110px'},
                    300);
                },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('#content')
                .animate({
                    height: '100px'},
                    300);
                }})
        .click(function() {
            $(this)
                .fadeOut( 1000 )
                .unbind('mouseenter')
                .unbind('mouseleave');
            $('#content')
                .animate({
                    height: '300px'},
                    500);
            $('#arrow_up')
                .delay(1000)
                .fadeIn( 2000 );
        });

    $('#arrow_up').bind({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('#content')
                .animate({
                    height: '290px'},
                    300);
                },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('#content')
                .animate({
                    height: '300px'},
                    300);
                }})
        .click(function() {
            $(this)
                .fadeOut( 1000 )
                .unbind('mouseenter')
                .unbind('mouseleave');
            $('#content')
                .animate({
                    height: '100px'},
                    500);
            $('#arrow_down')
                .delay(1000)
                .fadeIn( 2000 );
        });

    });
```

It is working nicely, but only the first time. You can check it here: http://www.cow-art.eu/test/index.html

I want to animate the content div on hovering an arrow below. After clicking it I want to slide it down to full size and after the next click - to hide it partially. You can check it on the link provided above. It's working fine, but the arrow hovering animation is working unless I show and hide the content. The second approach is not animating it as the first.

I assume it's because the clicking event is unbinding the mouseenter and mouseleave, and there is no other event what can bind it again.

I ran out of ideas how to fix it. Can you please help me with that one?

Comment: Ok, I came up with a solution for that problem.

I just replaced "height" with "paddingBottom" and adjusted it as I wanted to.

I posted it if somebody has similar problem. :)